# let the system call `select()` block until a socket gets something to read

Tags: c++, c, sockets, system-calls

In the man page of `select(int nfds, fd_set *readfds, fd_set *writefds, fd_set *exceptfds,
 struct timeval *timeout)`, it says:

```
If timeout is a null pointer, the select blocks indefinitely.
```

Does the *indefinitely* means a period with an arbitrary length?

Is is good to let a thread block at `select()` until the socket get some data? If so, what should the *timeout be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Indefinitely" is not arbitrary, it's forever. If the `timeout` pointer is `NULL`, then `select` will block forever, or until one of the file descriptors in one of the sets are "ready".

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Would you mind to provide some reference about `indefinitely = forever` for select()?

Comment: @user2207811 You can just check a dictionary, it's simply what the words means ("For an unlimited or unspecified period of time").

Comment: @user2207811 From [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/indefinitely): "without any limit of time or number". In other words, forever. :)

Comment: "shall block indefinitely **until at least one descriptor meets the specified criteria**." (emphasis mine) http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/select.html#tag_16_632)

Comment: Also note that `select` may return early due to signals, even ones intended to be non-interrupting: "If SA_RESTART has been set for the interrupting signal, it is implementation-defined whether the function restarts or returns with [EINTR]."

Answer (score 0):

No it is not a good idea to wait "forever"... If you unplug your network cable, your application will freeze. You should set a reasonable timeout (a few seconds perhaps) so that you can safely exit in case data never arrives.

Comment: It depends on what your application is doing. Generally, exiting when no data is received in a fixed amount of time is bad behavior...

Comment: If I unplug my network cable, everything will freeze. Because the application serves as a server.